# Why BindableObject.didChange must be a Subject?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Why BindableObject.didChange must be a Subject? 
Why cannot it be simple combination of other publishers?

I'm trying to implement BindableObject protocol.

I have two publishers: my model (movies) and latest error. I want didChange to emit new element when any of those do.

This is what I have with Publisher:

```
@Published var movies: [Movie] = []
//@Published var latestError: Error? = nil is not working
let latestError = CurrentValueSubject<Error?, Never>(nil)
...
var didChange: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        return $movies.map { _ -> Void in return () }
            .merge(with: latestError.map { _ -> Void in return () })
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

When I set movies `didChange` does not emit new event, or at least my view is not refreshing.

But it works when I use a Subject:

```
let didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    init() {
        $movies
            .map { _ -> Void in return () }
            .merge(with: latestError.map { _ -> Void in return () })
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .subscribe(didChange)
            .store(in: &disposeBag)
    }
```

Comment: FYI, as of beta 4, `didChange` still works (unless you work with List and maybe other things0 but the protocol requirement is now `willChange`. You probably want to make are you're using the latest. (they usually release betas every other week, and next Tuesday will likely be beta 5).

Comment: `willChange` was renamed to `objectWillChange`. Only sends from `objectWillChange` do get picked up by views now.